# Prevent Alt+Tab Switching out of Ionic iPad App

Tags: ios, keyboard, ionic-framework

How can I disable Alt-Tab from working while my iPad app is running?

I developed an iPad app using Ionic which is used at a gym for member self-service. The iPad has a Bluetooth keyboard connected to it to make data entry easier.

The problem now is that users use Alt-Tab to switch back to the home screen of the iPad and then use the iPad for personal stuff. The owner of the gym needs me to disable Alt-Tab while in the app.

Is there a way to register for keyboard events and then suppress something like Alt-Tab?

Comment: Search for information on guided access or you ca use Apple configurator to lock it in single app mode

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 Guided Access looks like it will solve the problem. Will give it a try.